# Euclid’s Proposition I.3 overused?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, math-history

Although the references to postulates, axioms, and previous propositions are not part of the original text of Euclid's *Elements*, all the editions I have seen contain them.

In many propositions, it is needed to make adjacent segments, say $PR$ and $PQ$ equal.  Examples include:

- [Proposition I.5](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~DJoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI5.html);
- [Proposition I.9](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~DJoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI9.html);
- [Proposition I.11](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~DJoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI11.html);
- [Proposition I.16](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~DJoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI16.html).

All the editions linked from [this page](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~DJoyce/java/elements/web.html) and more (I do not have enough reputation to post the links to them): John Casey’s English translation, Richard Fitzpatrick’s edition, Johan Ludvig Heiberg's edition, and Józef Czech's Polish translation refer in those cases to [Proposition I.3](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~DJoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI3.html) (“To cut off from the greater of two given unequal straight lines a straight line equal to the less”).

As I understand it, for making such adjacent segments equal, [Postulate 3](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~DJoyce/java/elements/bookI/post3.html) (“Let it be postulated to draw a circle with any center and radius”) is sufficient.  Why is Postulate 3 not referred to in all those editions of *Elements* instead of Proposition I.3?

[Uncontroversial uses of Proposition I.3 include [Proposition I.6](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~DJoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI6.html), where $DB$ is made equal to $AC$.]

Comment: Maybe because Post.3 is referred to in the proof of Prop.3... And probably the only use of Post.3 is in allowing to prove Prop.3...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Postulate 3 is used in [Proposition I.1](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI1.html), [Proposition I.2](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI2.html), Proposition I.3, and [Proposition I.22](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI22.html).

Comment: Related, perhaps the answer you are looking for: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682519/euclidean-proposition-8-of-book-i/2682526#2682526