# Intersection of a circle and a line with only compasses

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Recently I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710568/ruler-and-compasses-without-ruler-mohr-mascheroni) about Mohr-Mascheroni theorem. I read the paper  "[*A short elementary proof of the Mohr-Mascheroni Theorem*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.9902&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" by Norbert Hungerbuhler but was unsatisfied with it.

In **Construction 1** the author constructs intersection points of a circle with center $M$ and line non-passing a center of the circle given by two points.

The **Construction 1** is as follows:

> If the straight line $g$ is given by the points $P_1$ and $P_2$ we reflect the center $M$ of given circle $K$ with respect to $g$. (It is done by means of two circles one with center in $P_1$ and second with center in $P_2$ through $M$)   Then we find the two points of intersection $\{X,Y\}=K\cap g$ as the point of intersection of $K$ and the **reflected circle** $K'$.

[image]

As the user @Aretino indicated in comment on the recent question **Euclid's compass could only draw a circle given its center AND a point of the circle**, which was my point when I asked the recent question about an reference of alternative proof.

> So my question is: How to construct $\{X,Y\}$ as above with "Euclid's compass"?

I can't understand if construction of **reflected circle** is carried out in a correct way in the construction mentioned above, we have a center $M'$ of reflected circle, but haven't a point constructed to draw it through.

May be I misunderstood a Mohr-Mascheroni theorem, may be it is not about an "Euclide's compoass"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the construction is unclear, though it is easily fixed. We just need to reflect any point on circle $K$ through $g$. For example:

1. The point $Q$ is already constructed as the intersection of $K$ with the
   circle with centre $P_1$ through $M$.
2. Reflect $Q$ through $g$ to $Q'$ using the already given point
   reflection construction. (Circles with centres $P_1$ and $P_2$
   through $Q$, not shown in diagram.)
3. Construct $K'$ with centre $M'$ through $Q'$.

[image: Image of amended construction]

Alternatively, it is already known that a circle with a given radius can be reconstructed with a different centre using only a collapsing compass. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_equivalence_theorem#Alternative_construction_without_straightedge).

Comment: Oh, I see,   a reflection of Q does what was needed. Thank you wery much.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the numbered steps in order. I think every step is legitimate.

[image]