# For compass and straightedge problems, are you allowed to use the compass as a ruler?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

For compass and straightedge problems, you could have a line between two points A and B, and want to make a line the same size between C and line DE.

If you placed the two points of the compass between A and B, and made a circle around C with the same radius, that would achieve this result.

But is this something you are allowed to do?

Comment: Typically, constructions are described as being done with a "collapsible compass" or a "rusty (fixed) compass". With the former, it's not possible to transfer distances in the way you describe; with the latter, it *is* possible. Luckily, the ["Compass Equivalence Theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_equivalence_theorem) says that whatever is constructible with one type of compass is constructible with the other.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682519/euclidean-proposition-8-of-book-i/2682526#2682526

Comment: @Blue: Actually, I don't think you even need a compass if a segment of a circle is drawn somewhere on the plane, and you can if and where that segment of the circle intersects a line.  From what I recall, given such a segment and a line, one can determine if and where the line would intersect the whole circle.  From there, one can determine whether and where a line defined by two arbitrary points would intersect a circle defined by two arbitrary points.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD:  https://xkcd.com/866/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. Not by the rules about how to use compass and straightedge but because it can be proved that it's as if we could do it (that's [proposition 2 of book I of Euclid's *Elements*](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI2.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the specific construction of this query: The general rule in strictly classical Euclidean constructions is: The instruments cannot carry distance information from one step to another.  So, in particular: (a) The straightedge cannot be marked, not even at a single point; (b) The compass does retain its spacing while drawing any one circle, but forgets the spacing once the compass is 'lifted off of the plane'.  If you want to replicate a distance at a specific locale, you generally need auxiliary constructions (e.g parallel lines through a segment's endpoints).