# Elements, Euclid. Proposition 2

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

What is wrong with the following argument?

By Postulate 3, we describe a circle centered at $A$ with a distance $BC$. Pick any point on the boundary of the circle. Call this point $F$. By Postulate 1, we connect $A$ and $F$ in a straight line. By the def. of circles, $AF$ = $BC$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682519/euclidean-proposition-8-of-book-i/2682526#2682526

Comment: @EthanBolker That cleared up quite a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postulate 3 allows you to construct a circle centered on one end of the given length (to be used as the radius).  It does not justify constructing a circle centered on a point that is not an endpoint of the given segment.

Consequently, in your first line, one of $B$ or $C$ must be $A$.

Comment: "3. To describe a circle with any center and distance."

Maybe the notion got lost in the translation, but do you agree that it sounds like I can fix a center, and pick any arbitrary distance (to be used as radius), like BC in this case?

Comment: @ski : No.  The proposition 2 is how you show you *can* transport a specified distance over to a given point.  Postulate 3 allows you to produce a circle with a given center passing through a given point (so that the radius is the distance between the two given points).

Answer (score 1):

"Pick any point" isn't a thing that any of the axioms allow you to do.

Comment: Book I, Proposition 11

"Take an arbitrary point D on AC..."

Comment: Nobody's claiming that Euclid actually stuck to his axiom list.